# Required WebGL extensions detection

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, webgl-extensions

I am working on a WebGL (using [ThreeJs](http://threejs.org)) application that, obviously, shows 3D models, and we are using some effects (shaders), looking to make a test to know whether the user can run the app or not, I find a way to retrieve a list of the supported plugins in the used browser.

#### The Question:

the problem that I am facing is rather to know what are the required plugins for my application, is there a way to automatically detect them?

---

#### More details:

for further details I would specify an example of what I need:

1. In my MacBook Pro under Mac OSX Maverix, the application is working fine
2. Testing the application on my Lenovo Laptop, under Windows 7, then Windows 8, the application is not working, and the problem is cause by the [Bokeh2](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_dof2) Shader.

Examining the list of supported WebGL extensions I've found that there are some extension that are missing in Lenovo compared to Mac, so how can I tell which are the required extension that if missing will break the WebGL app.

This is a list of the extension I have in both, mac and lenovo.

#### In my Mac:

> ANGLE_instanced_arrays
>
> WEBKIT_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
>
> OES_element_index_uint
>
> OES_standard_derivatives
>
> OES_texture_float
>
> OES_texture_float_linear
>
> OES_texture_half_float
>
> OES_texture_half_float_linear
>
> OES_vertex_array_object
>
> WEBKIT_WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc
>
> WEBKIT_WEBGL_depth_texture
>
> WEBGL_draw_buffers
>
> WEBGL_lose_context
>
> WEBGL_debug_renderer_info

#### In my Lenovo:

> ANGLE_instanced_arrays
>
> WEBKIT_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
>
> OES_element_index_uint
>
> OES_standard_derivatives
>
> OES_texture_float
>
> OES_texture_half_float
>
> OES_texture_half_float_linear
>
> OES_vertex_array_object
>
> WEBKIT_WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc
>
> WEBGL_lose_context
>
> WEBGL_debug_renderer_info

#### The missing ones in Lenovo:

> OES_texture_float_linear
>
> WEBKIT_WEBGL_depth_texture
>
> WEBGL_draw_buffers

Comment: Related: http://webglstats.com

Comment: In `WebGLRenderer.js` look at function `initGL()`.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa yeah I know that website, it was helpful for me, but I don't see anything that can help me solve this issue

Comment: Use `gl.getSupportedExtensions()`

Comment: totally aside, most likely the lack of draw buffers support, given the year of the post.

Answer (score 5):

You can check for an extension by asking for it

```
var ext = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float_linear");
If (!ext) {
  alert("extension does not exist");
}
```

For three.js you can use

```
var gl = renderer.getContext();
```

To get the `WebGLRenderingContext`

In your case if the extension does not exist consider not using the bokeh2 shader

Otherwise, it's up to the app/framework/code to tell you which extensions are needed. I can think of 3 ways off the top of my head

1. The ideal way would be for the app to specific in the docs as in *Bokek2 needs extensions X, Y, and Z*.
2. The next best way would be to just look through the code and see what it's doing.
3. One other way would be to override `getExtension` and then (1) print out which extensions are being checked for and (2) return `null` for certain extensions and see when the code fails.

I'd really suggest #2 above but for #3 you could do this

```
(function() {

  var originalGetExtensionFunction = WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getExtension;

  // start with this array empty. Once you know which extensions
  // the app is requesting you can then selectively add them here
  // to figure out which ones are required.
  var extensionToReject = [
    "OES_texture_float",
    "OES_texture_float_linear",
  ];

  WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getExtension = function() {
    var name = arguments[0];
    console.log("app requested extension: " + name); 
    if (extensionToReject.indexOf(name) >= 0) {
      console.log("rejected extension: " + name);
      return null;
    } 
    var ext = originalGetExtensionFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log("extension " + name + " " + (ext ? "found" : "not found"));
    return ext;
  };

}());
```

Comment: thanks @gman but, looking at the question, this is not what I need. I want to know what extension are required for my webgl app

Comment: @Abu Creator of the app would use this code, and should notify you if your device/browser doesn't support all the features. Simply put, it's not for you to be concerned about app support, but creator's.

Comment: updated answer with 3 suggestions for finding out which extensions the app needs.

Comment: As an exercise left to the reader this seems like something that could be added to the [webgl inspector](http://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/). A list of extensions that have been enabled and then separately the ability to block some of them.

Comment: #2, this question should be the accepted answer it's as good as it's going to get short of writing an (unreliable) SAT. seems OP has expectation to "automatically detect" required extensions -- firstly, devs know what they use. second, GLSL provides directive `#extension` to declare the extension(s) a shader requires, and defines to macro different code depending on extension availability. This is in the "Basics" section of the Khronos GL ES Shading Language docs. "Basics." One could argue the bokeh samples make the mistake of not declaring their extension requirements, but, most don't.